# Jquery selectmenu combobox closes whenever button-up in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, knockout.js

In my html, I have this data binding

```
<select data-bind="options: graders,
    optionsText: 'LastName',
    optionsValue: 'Id',
    selectmenuValue: selectedGroup().GraderId,
    optionsCaption: 'Choose a grader'">
</select>
```

In my JavaScript, I have following to refresh the UI in real time

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectmenuValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        if (typeof ko.bindingHandlers.value.init !== 'undefined') {
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
        }
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        if (typeof ko.bindingHandlers.value.update !== 'undefined') {
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
        }
        $(element).selectmenu();
    }
};
```

Everything is working good in Firefox but on IE and Chrome, whenever I mouse up the combobox, its popup immediately closes. The popup should stay opened like in firefox. With many tries, I found that I can make it stay opened if I move my mouse from the first item to one of the other items while pressing its button and press up at the point.

Anybody knows how to fix this problem?

Update: I just realized that location of its popup is little off in IE and Chrome and I believe that's the reason of the behavior above. Still looking for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You want style to be set to 'dropdown' I believe

```
$(element).selectmenu({style: 'dropdown'});
```